# wxPython need some kind of tree representation

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have reached a point in my project from which I'm not sure how to continue. My current task is to give the user a possibility to create a folder structure for some custom projects. So basically the user should be able to add a new folder , add some data to the folder and of course visualize his project folder/data structure.
So basically I would need something similar to a jsTree.

Now my question is: is there any kind of widget already defined in wx that offers something similar to this? If (and I'm guessing there's a high probability ) something like this doesn't already exist, what do you recommend as an approach? My only idea so far would be to try to create this somehow using either a flexgridsizer with a lot of tweaking or some kind of recursive method that keeps adding sizers full of custom buttons until the folder tree ends , but I hope there are some better approaches to this problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, googling "wxpyhton tree" returns lots of wx.TreeCtrl info (it's how I first discovered it when I needed a tree representation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few widgets you could use:

[wx.TreeCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TreeCtrl-class.html) which would probably do everything you are looking to do.

An alternative widget that functions differently (Incorporates MVC) would be the [wx.lib.mvctree.MVCTree](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.mvctree.MVCTree-class.html)

There are even more again that you could customise (Most extending wx.TreeCtrl). Why don't you have a look at the [wxPython demo](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable) which will show you all the different controls works. It already shows the MVCTree control working with files.

Comment: Thank`s a lot.It`s just that I didn`t know where to start looking.I`ll give the demo a look ASAP.